# How to create a Integration Runtime with Managed Virtual Network using PowerShell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I would like to create an Azure hosted Integration Runtime with a Managed Virtual Network.
I'm able to create it using the ADF interface, however I would like to script it.

[image: ADF Portal - Integration runtime setup]

This is the code that I'm using.

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -Name $adfIntegrationRuntimeName `
-ResourceGroupName $adf.ResourceGroupName `
-DataFactoryName $adf.DataFactoryName `
-Type Managed `
-Description $adfIntegrationRuntimeDescription `
-Location $adf.Location `
-DataFlowTimeToLive 10 `
-DataFlowComputeType General `
-DataFlowCoreCount 8
```

This is the result with using the UI:

[image: JSON config - Azure IR with Managed Virtual Network]

And this is the result using the PowerShell code:

[image: JSON config - Azure IR subtype Public]

Do you know a way to provision an IR hosted on Azure with subtype "Managed Virtual Network" using PowerShell?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the Azure portal UI, this configuration is just in preview, there is no built-in parameter in command [`Set-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2integrationruntime?view=azps-5.7.0) to configure this, if you want to configure this via powershell, you can call the REST API - [`Integration Runtimes - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integrationruntimes/createorupdate) directly in powershell.

**Sample:**

```
$adfIntegrationRuntimeName = "test1"
$adfIntegrationRuntimeDescription = "123"
$ResourceGroupName = "xxxx"
$ADFname = "joyfactory"
$adf = Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $ADFname
$path = $adf.DataFactoryId + "/integrationruntimes/" + $adfIntegrationRuntimeName + "?api-version=2018-06-01"

$payload = @{
    "name" = $adfIntegrationRuntimeName
    "properties" = @{
        "type" = "Managed"
        "description" = $adfIntegrationRuntimeDescription
        "typeProperties" = @{
            "computeProperties" = @{
                "location" = $adf.Location
                "dataFlowProperties" = @{
                    "computeType" = "General"
                    "coreCount" = 8
                    "timeToLive" =  10
                }
            }
        }
        "managedVirtualNetwork" = @{
            "type" = "ManagedVirtualNetworkReference"
            "referenceName" = "default"
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path $path -Method PUT -Payload $payload
```

**Note:** The options below will not map in the `Code`, so if you want to enable it, you also need to run the command below after the commands above.

[image]

```
$path2 = $adf.DataFactoryId + "/integrationruntimes/" + $adfIntegrationRuntimeName + "/enableInteractiveQuery" + "?api-version=2018-06-01"
Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path $path2 -Method POST -Payload '{"autoTerminationMinutes":60}'
```

[image]

Check the result in the portal, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I have tried it and it works flawlessly. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Answer looks ideal but when I try, I get the response: "Invalid reference to the managed Virtual Network 'default'. The managed Virtual Network does not exist."

Comment: Here is also a nice solution from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint#create-a-managed-virtual-network-via-azure-powershell